DBI dbExecute not working with Oracle Database
I have a RJDBC-connection with an Oracle Database and run the following example:
dbWriteTable(con, "cars", head(cars, 3))
dbReadTable(con, "cars")   # there are 3 rows

This works fine. However, if I run the following line, I get an error:
dbExecute(con,"INSERT INTO cars (speed, dist) VALUES (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3)")

The error I get is:
Error in dbSendQuery(conn, statement, ...) : 
  Unable to retrieve JDBC result set
  JDBC ERROR: ORA-00933: SQL-Befehl was not correctly finished

  Statement: INSERT INTO cars (speed, dist) VALUES (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3)

Any idea what I am missing here? The example was taken from https://rdrr.io/cran/DBI/man/dbExecute.html.

Oracle does not support the syntax INSERT INTO cars (speed, dist) VALUES (1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3) until Oracle 23. As per the linked duplicate, either use INSERT ALL or INSERT INTO ... SELECT .... to insert multiple rows in a single statement.

I tried the following:
dbExecute(con,"INSERT ALL INTO cars(SPEED, DIST)  VALUES (1,2) SELECT * FROM dual")
but got another error:
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :
unable to find an inherited method for function ‘dbGetRowsAffected’ for signature ‘"JDBCResult"’

You probably need to ask a new question about that as it is a different problem and then hopefully an expert in R/DBI can tell you what the problem is.
